# Block Chrome password banner: "Use passwords saved in your Google Account"

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, google-accounts

The Google Chrome desktop browser on macOS is now prompting me whenever I click in a password field:

[image: Use passwords saved in your Google Account]

> Use passwords saved in your Google Account

When I click the banner, it shows:

[image: Use your Google Account to save and fill passwords?]

> Use your Google Account to save and fill passwords?
>
> Passwords from your Google Account will also be available on this device while you're signed in
>
> No thanks | Yes

Clicking "No thanks" does not permanently hide the banner. It still appears whenever I focus a password field.

How can I permanently block the password field banner?

I do not want to use a Google password manager.

The banner may also block the display of different password managers.

Comment: You should just be able to hit "Yes" and then just don't add any passwords/click No when it prompts you to.

Comment: I don't use Mac - but on Windows - I turned off "offer to save password" chrome://settings/passwords?search=password - and also cleared any password saved there (if any) and it never prompted me for that... but maybe Chrome Mac behaves differently?

Comment: @Darius if you want to add that as an Answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off **"Offer to save passwords"** at the Chrome settings URL below:

> chrome://settings/passwords?search=password

Also clear any passwords saved there (if any). It has never prompted me for password fill in Chrome.